# Html.Hidden() is not binding the right values in foreach loop

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a View that uses foreach loop to display the student list with a delete option. But the Html.hidden is not getting the correct student.ID as intended.

Here is my student class:

```
public class Student
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var students = db.Students.OrderBy(s => s.ID).ToList();
    return View(students);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeleteStudent(Guid Id)
{
    if (Id != null)
    {
        Student student = db.Students.Single(s => s.ID == Id);
        if (student == null)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
        db.Students.Remove(student);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View("Error");
}
```

My View

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.Student>
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Student List"; }
<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<ul>
@foreach (var student in Model)
{
    <li>
    @Html.displayFor(modelItem => student.Name)
    @using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteStudent", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.Hidden("Id", student.ID)
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btnSubmit">
    }
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

Say there are 3 students with ID's 1, 2 and 3 accordingly. But when I try to delete student 3, at the controller, the parameter `Guid Id` has the value 1, so the student with ID = 1 gets deleted.

In fact, no matter which student I delete, `Id` always takes the value of the first student on the list.

What am I doing wrong, or what's a better way to go about it?

Comment: Your model uses `@model MyProject.Models.Students` whereas the controller passes `Students.ToList()`. This is mismatch I guess. Try `@model MyProject.Models.Students[]`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I have added `IEnumerable` to my question. And it works now without changing to [TrueBlueAussie's Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29255346/4627429).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Revised answer

Having a second look at your requirements, the `@Html` helpers are not really giving any benefit to you. Your basic setup is that you are generating a large number of forms, each designed simply to delete one item. The minimum requirement is some way of identifying the item. The problem at the moment is that `@Html.Hidden` generates both a `name="ID"` and `id="ID"` and duplicate IDs are not allowed and cannot be processed correctly.

There are several ways I can think of to fix this:

1. Pass the id as a parameter to the form itself (my preferred solution)

e.g.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteStudent", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, new {id=student.ID})){
```

The controller just accepts an id value as is parameter. This means you do not need a hidden field.

2. Provide a single hidden value, via a *manually* generated hidden field

e.g.

```
<input name="ID" value="@student.ID" type="hidden"/>
```

The controller just accepts an id value as is parameter.

3. Use the `@Html.HiddenFor` as described below, but the controller action takes a generic `FormCollection` parameter and you pull out the individually named element (probably the worst option now).

### Original answer

As a rule, try to use `@Html.xxxFor` methods when you can. They then name items correctly for the postback.

As a second rule, you can't use `foreach` looks to render `@Html.xxxFor`s as those methods actually interpret the expression and look for an index value. A `foreach` does not provide an index value, so you have to use a simple `for` loop instead, so that the expressions can look like `Model[i].Property`.

e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.length; i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x=>Model[i].Name)
}
```

The indexing present in the expression results in a `name="Name[0]"`, `name="Name[1]"` etc in the input field.

Back to the question at-hand: you want a hidden field, for each form, so you should use the `for` loop and `@Html.HiddenFor` like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.length; i++)
{
    @using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteStudent", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.HiddenFor(x=>Model[i].ID)
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btnSubmit">
    }
}
```

Also, as mentioned in comment, your view `model` appears wrong. Generally you would use an `IEnumerable` or a `IList` like:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.Student>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! `HiddenFor` needs to be a lambda expression, so would it be `@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model[i].ID)`? What do I change the controller parameter to - something like `DeleteStudent(Student postbackstudent)`?

Comment: That was a cut & paste error (the first example was correct, have fixed the second). The controller methods may need a more generic `FormCollection` as the ID passed back will change in this example. I will need to take a look at your original question again as repeating the name only would be valid, so long as you do not repeat to ID too. i.e. use a manual `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="@student.Id"/>` rather than the HTML helper.

Comment: @Ramesisiii: Added several options for you. Adding routing to the forms is probably the simplest solution, but option 1 or 2 are both good.

Comment: Thanks for ending my battle with `Html.Hidden()`!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the reason you're always getting the same GUID is because all of your hidden input controls have the same ID.

If memory serves, when MVC tries to map a parameter to a form element, it will match on the first field, query string variable, and so on,  that matches the parameter name (case-insensitive).

Your form has multiple hidden input controls, all named "ID". Only the first one will be mapped to your DeleteStudent action's ID parameter. The rest of them will likely be ignored.